AR(1) regression with differenced variables interpretation
I am running a time series regression with 6 explanatory variables, which are economic variables over time (e.g., GDP, interest, M1 stock, tax revenue, etc.).
All variables (including the dependent variable [inequality]) have been logged and also first-differenced due to previous non-stationarity.My model also includes lagged differenced variables for 3 of the variables.
I am trying to understand the interpretation of the coefficients of the both the ordinary differenced variables and the lagged variables.
Do the ordinary differenced variables show only the short-term same period affects (e.g. effect of GDP growth on inequality growth in the same year) or do they show the overall long-term relationship between the variables? Does the fact they are differenced mean anything - my research up to now suggests no?
Does the lagged variable then show the effect of GDP growth on inequality the next period?

Note that $\log_e(x_{t+1}) - \log_e(x_{t+1}) \approx \frac{x_{t+1}-x_t}{x_t}$ at least when these are small in magnitude; for example $\log_e(102) - \log_e(100) \approx 0.0198\approx 2% =\frac{102-100}{100}$. So you are regressing short-term proportionate changes.  Whether these are same-period or lagged depends on the the variables in question.  The difficulty with long-term relationships for a single country is that this regression may not be able to distinguish them from independent trends for the various variables.
